# Flutter: generate a List of Widgets with data from Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, gridview, google-cloud-firestore

I want my screen to display a limited number of products in `GridView`.
All products are stored in the Firebase Firestore and their images are in the Firebase storage.
In order to do that I use `GridView.count`, which one of its parameters is `List<Widget> children`. I wanted to generate a List using `List.generate` and each time fetch a product from the Firestore and its image from the storage to create a widget that represents a product.
The problem is that fetching the products from Firebase is asynchronous, and the `generator` function of `List.generate` cannot be `async`. Moreover I'm returning `Future<List<Widget>>` instead of `List<Widget>` to the `children` param of `GridView.count`
Any ideas of how to overcome this?

here is my code:

```dart
GridView.count(
  primary: false,
  crossAxisCount: 2,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
  crossAxisSpacing: 10,
  mainAxisSpacing: 10,
  //FIXME: The argument type 'Future<List<Widget>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Widget>':
  children: _buildGridTileList(15),
)

Future<List<Widget>> _buildGridTileList(int count) async {
    var counterCollection = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Products").doc("Counter").get();
    var counterData = counterCollection.data();
    return List.generate(
      count,
      (index) async {
        //FIXME: Doesn't work beacuse generator cannot be async!!
        var avatarUrl = await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('${counterData[index]}').child('${counterData[index]}').getDownloadURL();
        return Container(
          child: Center(
            child: NetworkImage(avatarUrl),
          ),
        );
      }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have async code in your build function because it's the function assembling the widget tree to render immediately to the screen, instead what you do is use a StreamBuilder widget which gives you access to async events, the stream is listening to future data arriving from Firebase and rebuilds that section of the widget tree when the asynchronous event arrives. here is how it's done, this code should be close to what you need:

```
return StreamBuilder(
  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Products").snapshots(),
  builder:
  (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
    return Container();
  } else {
    return GridView.count(
      primary: false,
      crossAxisCount: 2,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
      crossAxisSpacing: 10,
      mainAxisSpacing: 10,
      children: List.generate(snapshot.data.docs.length, (index) {
        return Image.network(snapshot.data.docs[index].imageUrl);
        }),
      );
    }
  });
}
```